# Generalizing a proof of Cauchy's Theorem

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ a prime dividing $|G|$. There is a nice proof of Cauchy's Theorem in Aluffi's "Algebra Chapter 0" that makes use of an action (by cyclic permutation) of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ on the set of tuples $(x_1,\ldots,x_p)$ with $x_i\in G$ such that $x_1\cdots x_p=1$. Essentially, the argument shows that the set of fixed points of this action, namely, the collection of tuples of the form $(x,\ldots,x)$ with $x^p=1$, must have size divisible by $p$, and since $(1,\ldots,1)$ is in there, we get an element of order $p$.

I noticed that this argument can be extended to prove the following: If $G$ is a finite group, $p$ divides $|G|$, $\emptyset\neq H\subseteq Z(G)$, and $N$ denotes the number of $x\in G$ with $x^p\in H$, then $p$ divides $N$. For the proof, consider the set of tuples $S=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_p): x_i\in G, x_1\cdots x_p\in H\}$. We can count the number of elements of $S$ as follows: For any $h\in H$, we may choose $x_1,\ldots,x_{p-1}$ arbitrarily before $x_p=(x_1\cdots x_{p-1})^{-1}h$ is determined. This shows (I think) that $|S|=|G|^{p-1}|H|$, a multiple of $p$. Now, if $(x_1,\ldots,x_p)\in S$, then $x_1\cdots x_p=h$ for some $h\in H$. Since $h\in Z(G)$, we have $x_2\cdots x_p=x_1^{-1}h=hx_1^{-1}\implies x_2\cdots x_px_1=h\implies (x_2,\ldots,x_p,x_1)\in S$. So, we get an action of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ on $S$ by cyclic permutation, as in the proof of Cauchy's Theorem. Again, the fixed points are the "constant" tuples in $S$, and the formula $|S|=|\{$fixed points$\}|+\sum\{$sizes of nontrivial orbits$\}$ shows that $p$ divides $N$.

Of course, we can now quickly deduce Cauchy's Theorem by setting $H=\{1\}$ and noting that since $1^p=1$, $N\geq p$.

My questions are: Is the above result well-known? Is it interesting? Am I overcomplicating something simple?

Comment: Looks correct. I've never seen the result as written, but note that you cannot conclude that $S$ contains any fixed points (the proof of Cauchy's Theorem relies on the fact that we can produce at least one element in the set of fixed points, namely $(1,1,\ldots,1)$, which might explain why this particular phrasing would not be explicit anywhere. It is an application of a general result that says that if you have a group whose order is a power of $p$ acting on a set $S$, then $|S|\equiv|S_0|\pmod{p}$, where $S_0$ is the set of fixed points of the action.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it occurred to me that the number N may be zero.

Comment: I'm trying to extract something interesting from this result. I suppose we can say that if H={g}, where g (a central element) has order dividing p-1, then the p-tuple (g,...,g) will belong to the above set S. Hence, we can use the argument to conclude that N is at least p, so there is some x different from g such that x^p = g. Maybe this is a more proper generalization of Cauchy's Theorem? A statement on p-th roots of central elements?

Comment: Any element of order prime to $k$ has a $k$th root: if the order is $n$, write $1=an+bk$. Then $g=g^{an+bk}=(g^n)^a(g^b)^k=(g^b)^k$, so $g^b$ is a $k$th root of $g$. As $p-1$ is prime to $p$, the fact that it has a $p$th root if it has order $p-1$ is a trivial corollary (also, $g=g^p$...).

Comment: Is it nontrivial that g has a p-th root other than itself, though? For instance, are we guaranteed that g^b is not the same as g? It seems that the statement that "g central with |g| dividing p-1 ==> g has a p-th root other than itself" shouldn't be trivial, because it generalizes Cauchy's Theorem, a nontrivial statement.

Comment: We know $G$ has elements of order $p$, so then if $x$ has order $p$, $gx$ (when $g$ is central of order dividing $p-1$) is a $p$th root of $g$; so are $gx^2,\ldots,gx^{p-1}$, which together with $g$ give you the $p$ elements you are guaranteed to have by your calculation. It is a trivial consequence of Cauchy's Theorem, without having to reproduce the proof.

Comment: As to $g^b\neq g$ in the calculation above, that holds if and only if $b\not\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, which happens if and only if $k\not\equiv 1\pmod{n}$. So in many instances you will demonstrably have it. For Cauchy's Theorem you have $n=1$, though, so $k\not\equiv1\pmod{n}$ never holds.

Comment: I do want to point out that what you are doing is good work. It's always a good idea to see how far one can push an argument, or try to figure out exactly how much you need to push it through. What I'm pointing out is just why you probably wouldn't see this particular conclusion written out or highlighted in the literature.

Comment: Thanks! Your comments were really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I would call your result "well-known", but it is a special case of some other results which are at least known.

Let $G$ be a finite group. Frobenius' theorem (1895) states the following.

> **Theorem:** Let $n \mid |G|$. Then the number of solutions to $x^n = 1$ in $G$ is a multiple of $n$.

More generally, Frobenius (1903) proved:

> **Theorem:** Let $c \in G$ and $n > 0$ integer. The number of solutions to $x^n = c$ in $G$ is a multiple of $\gcd(n, |C_G(c)|)$.

> **Theorem:** Let $C$ be a conjugacy class in $G$ and $n > 0$ an integer. The number of elements in $G$ with $x^n \in C$ is a multiple of $\gcd(n|C|,|G|)$.

(There is a proof in "Theory of Finite Groups" by Marshall Hall Jr., Theorem 9.1.1.)

As a corollary:

> **Theorem:** Let $c \in Z(G)$ and $n > 0$ integer. The number of solutions to $x^n = c$ in $G$ is a multiple of $\gcd(n,|G|)$.

So if $p \mid |G|$ is a prime and $c \in Z(G)$, the number of solutions to $x^p = c$ in $G$ is a multiple of $p$. Thus giving your observation, although the proofs of the above results are different. The proof of Cauchy's theorem that you mention is due to McKay (1959), and basically proves Frobenius' theorem for $n = p$ prime.

These theorems by Frobenius have been generalized by many authors, and there are many different proofs. For example, Philip Hall proved many results on the number of solutions to more general equations in finite groups.

**EDIT:** We could generalize the argument of McKay that appears in your question as follows. Let $p$ be a prime dividing $|G|$.

Suppose that $X \subseteq G$ is a subset of $G$ which is closed under conjugation. Consider $$S = \{ (x_1, \ldots, x_p) : x_1 \cdots x_p \in X \}.$$ Then $|S| = |X| |G|^{p-1}$, and $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ acts on $S$ by cyclic permutation. Therefore the number of elements with $x^p \in X$ is a multiple of $p$. From this we get a special case of Frobenius' theorem.

> **Theorem:** Let $n \mid |G|$ and let $p \mid n$ be a prime. Then the number of solutions to $x^n = 1$ in $G$ is a multiple of $p$.

> **Proof:** Let $X = \{x \in G : x^{n/p} = 1\}$, which is a subset closed under conjugation. The number of solutions to $x^n = 1$ is the number of elements such that $x^p \in X$, so the result follows from the observation above.

In particular we have a proof of Frobenius' theorem in the case where $n$ is squarefree. The above proof is basically the one given by Sachs (1960).

References:

[1] F. G. Frobenius, Verallgemeinerung des Sylow'schen Satzes, Sitzungsberichte der Königl. Preuß. Akad. der Wissenschaften (Berlin) (1895), 981-993.

[2] F. G. Frobenius, Über einen Fundamentalsatz der Gruppentheorie, Sitzungsberichte der Königl. Preuß. Akad. der Wissenschaften (Berlin) (1903), 987-991.

[3] P. Hall, On a Theorem of Frobenius, Proc. London Math. Soc., 40,
468-501, (1935).

[4] J. H. McKay, Another proof of Cauchy's group theorem. Amer. Math. Monthly 66 (1959), 119.

[5] H. Sachs, Einfacher Beweis des Frobeniusschen Fundamentalsatzes der Gruppentheorie für den Fall eines quadratfreien Exponenten. Acta Sci. Math. (Szeged) 21 (1960), 309-310.

Comment: Super interesting. I hadn't run into those 1903 theorems.

Comment: These theorems are somewhat less known compared to other things in group theory. Frobenius had some applications for these results - I think in most group theory textbooks they are proven with other, more useful methods (e.g. transfer homomorphism).